# Can't open pdf in new Chrome browser tab

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, pdf, tabs

I can't figure out how to open a pdf in a new Chrome tab.  The following code works on Internet Explorer but not for Chrome.  I checked the setting in Chrome and it is set to the following:

[image]

My view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View", "OpenFileEncrypted", "Storage", new { fileNumber = item.accession_number, fileType = 2, openType = "NewTab" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary ViewDownloadButton", @runat="server", @target = "_blank", @onclick = "javascript:clickView(" + item.accession_number + ")" })
```

The javascript function ClickView checks a checkbox on the web
page.

My Controller:

```
 public ActionResult OpenFileEncrypted(int? fileNumber, int? fileType, string openType)
    {            
      CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(      
      CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

      CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

      CloudBlobContainer container = GetContainer(blobClient, Convert.ToInt32(fileType));

      KeyVaultKeyResolver cloudResolver = new KeyVaultKeyResolver(GetToken);

      var fileName = Convert.ToString(fileNumber) + ".pdf";
      CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

      BlobEncryptionPolicy policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(null, cloudResolver);
      BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions() { EncryptionPolicy = policy };

      var memStream = new MemoryStream();
      blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memStream, null, options, null);

      if (openType == null)
      {
       openType = "NewTab";
      }

      order_info OInfo = Ldb.order_info.Where(o => o.accession_number == fileNumber).FirstOrDefault();

       switch (openType)
       {
         case "NewTab":
             Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Inline; filename=" + fileName);
             OInfo.ReportViewed = true;
             break;
         case "Download":
             Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
             OInfo.ReportDownloaded = true;
             break;
       }

       if (OInfo != null)
       {
          Ldb.Entry(OInfo).State = EntityState.Modified;
          Ldb.SaveChanges();
       }

       return File(memStream.ToArray(), blockBlob.Properties.ContentType);
```

It works in IE but not Chrome.  When the button is clicked it opens a new tab then opens a download box to name and select the folder where the .pdf is downloaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Must be extention pdf

Answer (score 0):

I had to update the update the ContentType to "application/pdf"

```
return File(memStream.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
```

The ContentType was "application/octet-stream"